# MATLAB: Converting a calendarDuration array into String

Tags: matlab

I have some code to measure how long a simulation takes, and I cannot manage to simply print the time difference as a string:

```
t1 = datetime('now'); 

% spend somme time... 
for i = 1:20000000
    m = log(1234); 
end 

t2 = datetime('now'); 
dt = between(t1,t2)
fprintf('t1 = %s\nt2 = %s\ndt = %s\n',datestr(t1),datestr(t2),datestr(dt));
```

See the output below. I am aware that dt is a calendarDuration array, but I cannot figure out how to print it, didn't find something in the documentation, too. Employing cellstr, as indicated in the error message, didn't work.

```
>> test_for_reading_mat

dt = 

   0h 0m 1.156s

Error using calendarDuration/datestr (line 616)
You cannot convert a calendarDuration array to date strings. Use
CELLSTR instead.

Error in test_for_reading_mat (line 11)
fprintf('t1 = %s\nt2 = %s\ndt =
%s\n',datestr(t1),datestr(t2),datestr(dt));
```

Is somebody aware of a simple solution?

Comment: why dont you just do `char(t2-t1)` ? and why dont you use `tic` , `toc`?

Comment: Thank you very much! char(t2-t1) was the kind of simple solution I was looking for.